# Multiple Service Definition in Config File Not Working Consul

Tags: consul

I have been trying to add multiple service through configuration in consul.

But Consul UI is throwing error at startup of the agent itself.

The error is:-

```
$consul.exe agent --dev
Starting Consul agent...
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
github.com/hashicorp/consul/agent.(*Agent).loadServices(0xc0421268c0, 
0xc04223aa80, 0xc042254a00, 0x0)
/gopath/src/github.com/hashicorp/consul/agent/agent.go:2097 
github.com/hashicorp/consul/agent.(*Agent).Start()
/gopath/src/github.com/hashicorp/consul/agent/agent.go:326 
github.com/hashicorp/consul/command.(*AgentCommand).run()
/gopath/src/github.com/hashicorp/consul/command/agent.go:704
github.com/hashicorp/consul/command.(*AgentCommand).Run()
/gopath/src/github.com/hashicorp/consul/command/agent.go:653
```

Config file is:-

```
{
"Services": [{
    "id": "somename",
    "name": "nameofthissevice",
    "service": "myservice",
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 62133,
    "enableTagOverride": false,
    "tags" : ["service1"]
},
{
    "id": "somename1",
    "name": "nameofthissevice",
    "service": "myservice2",
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 64921,
    "enableTagOverride": false,
    "tags" : ["service2"]
}]
```

}

I am using Win 7 platform.

Could any one suggest some ideas in it.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file is not loaded, so the problem is not in the file, in order to load the configuration file you should add another flag for loading the configuration, otherwise consul will start with default configuration.

Looks like a faulty binary or incompatible version.

Your windows7 is a 32 bit arch or 64?
And which exec version of consul have you downloaded ?